# Como saber se um arquivo existe através de sua url sem precisar baixa-lo?

Tags: c#

Tenho uma lista de arquivos e preciso saber se foi feito upload num serviço de armazenamento. A ideia para facilitar o processo é concatenar o nome do arquivo, gerar uma URL e tentar fazer download do arquivo, se retornar 404 eu meu método retorna `false`.

```
public static bool ThumbExist(string contributorID,string imageID)
{
    string url = String.Format("https://servico.com/file/{0}/{1}.jpg", contributorID, imageID);
    byte[] myDataBuffer;
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    myWebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
    try
    {
        myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(url);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) //Quando não existe o servidor retorna um 404 e cai aqui
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Como posso verificar **APENAS** se o servidor me retorna no mínimo 1 `byte` sem precisar baixar a imagem toda.

Preciso disso pois se a imagem existe, meu código baixa ela por completo e isso leva tempo desnecessário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se usar o WebRequest em vez do WebClient pode verificar o tamanho do ficheiro.

**Exemplo:**

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.example.com/"));
request.Method = "HEAD";

using(WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", response.ContentLength, response.ContentType);
}
```